# PyMOL to work on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymol

I am writing a program which will need to use pymol, at the moment I have only added "import pymol" to my code. I am trying find a way to not get error "no module named pymol". So pymol (which now works with python 3) is only available to install via conda (https://pymol.org/2/support.html), although, when I follow the link, it seems that this is the same installation for python 2.7. I follow that link, install it via conda, but pymol is only showing in my python 2.7 folder. If pymol developers are saying that pymol should work on python 3, is there something I am doing wrong? I have previously had issues with vtk, where I installed it, but it was also not found because of the path where it was I think. I somehow fixed it, but no luck with pymol. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. you can probably tell I am new to programming so please bear with me.

Comment: Sorry, what is your *question*? If it's "how can I get this working?" I'm afraid that's a little too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyMOL seems to have limited support for Python 3.

> Does PyMOL support Python 3?
>
> We recommend Python 2.7 for production use! Python 3.6 packages for macOS and Linux are available in our Anaconda channel. Be advised that issues with PyMOL session files and third party plugins or scripts are possible.

You probably need to familirise yourself [environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), this is a ways to isolate different sets of packages. I suggest creating a separate environment with python 3 and pymol

```
conda create --no-default-packages -n env1 python=3.6 pymol
```

or without `--no-default-packages` flag if you wish a larger set of packages:

```
conda create -n env1 python=3.6 pymol
```

then change to that environment, if creation is successful:

```
source activate myenv
```

`import pymol` should work here.

If not - try installing pymol using [channels](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html), provided [their channel](https://anaconda.org/schrodinger/pymol).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although not exactly the solution, you lead me in the right direction, so now solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.Bg you can edit the answer to provide the exact solution so other benefits from this.